# black left- / right-pointing triangles not the same size

Tags: html, encoding, geometry, character

I'm using the black left pointing triangle / right left pointing triangle geometric shapes as links on a website, using their HTML codes ( ◀ and ▶):

```
&#9664;
&#9654;
```

For some reason, the triangles are not displayed in the same size, even when I'm using them on a blank page with no other elements.

On Chrome, the left pointing one is slightly larger than the right pointing one.
On Firefox, the right pointing one is much larger then the left pointing one.

I have the problem even when there's no CSS at all, on an otherwise blank page.

Any idea what the reason might be or how to fix this?

Comment: Try to change `font-family` until you like it size

Comment: Does this problem apply to this page as well? Do the triangles in your question appear to be different in size?

Comment: On this page, it looks fine!

Comment: I tried to add the same font-family like on this page, but on mine the triangles still have different sizes. Also, even if I change the the font-size, the difference remains, i.e. both get smaller/bigger, but relative to each other, one remains taller than the other.

Comment: Same here; they look the same. If all else fails, you could try other shapes, such as the left/right pointing pointer ◄ ► or left/right pointing small triangle ◂ ▸.

Comment: In principle, the problem might arise if the characters are taken from different fonts. In practice, all fonts that I know of contain either both of these characters or neither of them. Can you please provide a testable document that demonstrates the problem (full HTML code, or jsfiddle)?

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

◄ and ►

&#9668 and &#9658

Comment: Changing my encoding from &#9654 to &9658 made it much more consistent across browsers. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Just repeating Mr Lister's comment as an answer, as it worked for me (vote his comment up!)

"... If all else fails, you could try other shapes, such as the left/right pointing pointer ◄ ► or left/right pointing small triangle ◂ ▸." – Mr Lister

I copy/pasted the pointing pointer characters from this comment and it was a consistent size in FF/Chrome/IE.

P.S. Changing the font family didn't make any difference for me.

Comment: That certainly did the trick! Somehow the left- and right-pointing triangles get a different size in different browsers, also they scale very badly, while the pointers look just perfect. Now there aren't any up and down pointers, but oddly enough the up ▲ and down ▼ triangles both work perfect, and have the same shape and width as the pointers (great if you alternate between the 2).

Comment: The ▲ and ▼ have _almost_ the same shape as ◄ and ►, I might add - if you want it to be 100% better use transform: rotate.

For dec and hex codes see [link](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp)

Answer (score 6):

I kept hitting this same problem with character after character. In the end I used the same arrow, triangle, pointer for both right and left. In my case I used a right facing arrow for both the right and left pointers. I flipped the left arrow using `transform: scale(-1)`. Now they look identical.

Comment: This flip the baseline upside down, though. You’re better off using a horizontal flip instead: `rotateY(180deg)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Aye Mon Chit!

I had originally used the following:
◄ - &#9664    and    ► - &#9654

And it all seemed to be working fine on all browsers, until i tried it on smartphones. Did not work at all...

So I used the following:
◄ - &#9668    and    ► - &#9658

and it works in all browsers, including smartphone internet.

FYI. This page is really helpful.
http://graphemica.com/%E2%97%84