# Unicode triangles different sizes

Tags: html, unicode

I'm trying to put two unicode triangles next to each other (`&#9664;` and `&#9654;`), and the left one is slightly smaller than the right. Same typeface, same font-size. To wit:

## ◀ ▶

Any ideas why this is the case?

**EDIT: check out the fiddle. The effect is reversed there!** http://jsfiddle.net/CM6w3/1/

Comment: They both look the same size to me...

Comment: Just added a screenshot

Comment: They are probably taken from different fonts. Uncommon, but possible. Please post minimal HTML and CSS code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: The fiddle renders the triangles the same size Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m on Windows 7

Comment: TL;DR: You can't really ever depend on characters rendered by fonts to have any one particular fixed look...

Comment: I can confirm that the triangles have a different size on Chrome / OS X.

Comment: It only comes correct in FF. IE is showing them very small. Chrome a bit bigger but not actual size.

Comment: Changing my encoding from &#9654 to &9658 made it much more consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried several of the web safe fonts as [given by the W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp).

Of them, **Comic Sans MS** seemed to render the arrows correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/CM6w3/2/

```
<body>
  <span style='font-size: 8em; font-family:Comic Sans MS;'>
    &#9664;&#9654;
  </span>
</body>
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995873/black-left-right-pointing-triangles-not-the-same-size